# How to refresh vim layout when split

Tags: vim, layout

After setting up some splits/vsplits and resizing gvim or the console running vim, splitter positions are not updated. Is there a way to force updating splitter positions (by retaining them in the same relative position, say split at 50% of the current view)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

CTRL+W is all things splits:

- `CTRL+W,+` - enlarges the current split panel
- `CTRL+W,-` - shrinks the current split panel
- `CTRL+W,=` - evens the split panels size
- `CTRL+W,CTRL+W` - moves the focus to the next split panel

I believe you're looking for `CTRL+W,=`